# In Javascript or jQuery, how to detect whitespace in beginning of string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, whitespace

Given the following string:

```
htmlStr1 = " <div>This is a string with whitespace in the beginning</div> ";
htmlStr2 = "<div>This is a string with no whitespace in the beginning</div> ";
```

Is there a way to write a function that can detect if this string has a whitespace in the very beginning only?

e.g., it should do the following:

```
alert( checkBeginningWhiteSpace(htmlStr1) ); // should return "true"
alert( checkBeginningWhiteSpace(htmlStr2) ); // should return "false"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions) and the [RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

```
function checkBeginningWhiteSpace(str){
   return /^\s/.test(str);
}
```

The \s matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed and line feed.

Comment: This only checks to see if there is one whitespace. You really want /^\s+/

Comment: it is enough to check only the first character to be sure that a string beginns with white space.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was thinking of the case where you want to remove leading whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should match the beginning of the line, followed by one or more space characters (including tabs). This should be what you need, unless `nbsp;` also needs to recognize as a space.

```
htmlStr1.match(/^\s+/)
```